# Get Ids of rows that has duplicates in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table `users`

```
id | phone    
--------------
1  | +1111    
2  | +2222    
3  | +3333    
4  | +4444    
5  | +1111
```

I need to get all ids, where users have duplicate `phone`. For example, the query must return the following dataset: [1,5]. Because user with id 1 has phone +1111 and user with id 5 has phone +1111.

There is something close in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39693563/7542937). But I need to modify it for mysql. Currently, I have the following sql:

```
select  group_concat(id) as id from users
group by  phone
having count(id) > 1
```

But it returns a response with not wery good format. See:

[image]

Of corse, the reason is `group_concat`.

So, I need to get result as list of ids, not list of groups. Ho to do that for mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, the *Group Sum* should be the preferred solution on MySQL 8, but this is a perfect case for a simple Subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE phone IN
 (
   SELECT phone
   FROM users
   GROUP BY phone
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 )
```

If you need to display the actual count, go with Tim's solution.

Comment: Thank you! Simple and clean solution! Really good case for subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select id, phone
from (select u.*, count(*) over (partition by phone) as cnt
      from users
      group by  phone
     ) u
where cnt > 1;
```

My recommended solution in older version is `exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where exists (select 1
              from users u2
              where u2.phone = u.phone and u2.id <> u.id
             );
```

With an index on `users(phone, id)`, I would expect this to be the fastest solution -- even faster than the window functions approach.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer but it gives me an error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by phone) as cnt from users" I use 5.7 mysql

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak . . . You should upgrade to a more recent version of MySQL.  And, if using old versions, you should tag the question correctly.  But I added an alternative which I think has the best performance.

Answer (score 1):

To complement Gordon's MySQL 8+ solution, I thought I would chime in with an approach for earlier versions of MySQL:

```
SELECT u1.*
FROM users u1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT phone
    FROM users
    GROUP BY phone
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) u2
    ON u1.phone = u2.phone
```

Comment: Yes! It works for me! I just use `u1.id` instead of `u1.*` and have the list of ids. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution without sub-query:

```
SELECT users.id, users.phone
FROM users
JOIN users phones on phones.phone = users.phone
GROUP BY users.id, users.phone
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Live fiddle [here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=f2dce77f6f45c5b0a2e51ad02b6f1b58&php_version=php5&sql_version=mysql57)